# Java socket redirection

Tags: java, port, serversocket

I have a computer (A) running some service on port 2000 behind a block all incoming firewall/NAT etc...

With only a Java application is it possible to provide access to the local service on port 2000 from outside the network assuming you have another computer externally you can also run a Java application on.

You have a Java server socket (port 3000) on computer (B) which is expecting connections from computer A only. The Java application on computer (B) will also listen on port 4000 for client connection and forward any traffic to down the 3000 port and vice versa.

Client (Smilie) on the internet can connect to port 4000 on computer (B) which will forward everything via the incoming socket connected to on port 3000 which will then redirect to port 2000 on computer (A).

Assuming you need a persistent TCP connection which would be effectively transparent to the client software and the service how would go go about it ? Is it as simple as taking anything from one inputsteam and pushing to the others output stream and vice versa ? Or is there a better way to do this in Java ?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  What you are describing is possible.  It is effectively a "tcp over tcp tunnel".  Whether it is advisable is another matter.  See below.

> Assuming you need a persistent TCP connection which would be effectively transparent to the client software and the service how would go go about it ?

The Java application on B needs to have two ServerSockets.  One for the connection to A on port 3000, and the other for port 4000.

The Java application on A needs to open a socket to B:3000.  (It cannot happen the other way around because of the firewall).  Then it waits for data on that socket from B.

When B gets a connection on B:4000, it start a thread to copy the data from the B:4000 socket to the B:3000 socket, and another one to copy in the other direction

Then A gets the first data from B, it opens a connection to A:2000, and sets up threads to copy in both directions.

And you are away.

If you need to tunnel multiple connections over this tunnel, then the A <-> B protocol needs to multiplex the traffic; i.e. multiple streams from clients to A's service going over a single A <-> B socket.  And you may want to use selectors rather than a pair of threads per connection.

<sup>(Q: Will I find or write example code for you?  A: No.  Because ... see below.)</sup>

---

> Or is there a better way to do this in Java ?

Not in Java.  But there are non-Java alternatives.

---

So is this advisable?

IMO no.

- If you are going to do this using "user space" programs:

  - There may be an existing off-the-shelf application to do this.
  - If you are going to code this yourself, you are better off implementing it in C rather than Java.  (But Java would work ...)
- From a performance perspective, it would be better to implement this using a firewall hole; i.e. set things up so that the B is able to connect to A:2000, and use iptables or something to route connections from B:4000 to A:2000.  It will be a lot more efficient than routing data through user-space apps on two machines.
- From a security perspective, the firewall is in place for a reason.  Someone who *presumably* understands what they are doing, *and* has the authority to decide, has decided that incoming connections shouldn't be allowed (in general).  They will have **reasons** for making that decision.

  By setting up this tunnel to allow clients to connect to A:2000 you would be subverting the firewall.  You *should* at least get permission to do this from whoever manages the firewalls for your organization.

Comment: This is only a concept to connect to my own solar panels which is behind a GSM - NAT. What are the non-java alternatives you would recommend ?

Comment: I would recommend searching for alternatives.  But if >you< manage the firewall, then creating a firewall hole (with appropriate safeguards) could be the answer.  For example using SSL (or HTTPS) with client certs, firewall rules that only allow connections from external IPs or networks, etc.